# Applescript: Check if computer is playing any sound

Tags: audio, applescript, system

Trying to find a way for my script to check if there's any sound/audio being played currently on the computer. And if so, is there any way to find which app is playing sound?

Comment: Guess i need to run some kind of shell script

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this helps:

One thing that happens when a sound is played is that the power management blocks the computer to go to sleep. With `pmset -g` you can see all the Power Management stuff that is going on.

So, when sleep is prevented by "coreaudiod" the machine is playing obviously some sound.

Here what `pmset -g` spits out when iTunes is playing:

```
Currently in use:
 womp                 0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by iTunes, coreaudiod)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: If what he means is checking for iTunes, pandora, any web service etc is playing music, this is brilliant.

Comment: i tried this out, but pmset -g still shows coreaudiod when the sound is paused. Also, How to know which app is playing the sound?

Comment: Just to be sure: pause  all audio and check again with 'pmset -g'. I tested it with iTunes and other audio playing apps (AVAudioPlayer). But, true, to know the process that plays the audio, this approach isn't very useful unless you only need to know if it's iTunes that is playing (or any other app that announces it's name).